# How do I change an individual tab's width?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to change with width of React-Navigation tabs with scrollEnabled.  I want to decrease the width of each tab.

Here is my code:

```
tabBarOptions: {
  style: { 
    width:100
  } 
}
```

However, this changes the whole tab size and I only want to decrease the individual sizes of tabs.

I also tried this with no success:

```
  tabStyle: {
    width: 100
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to have dynamic size tabs ? Like, different width of different tabs or same small width of different tabs ?

Comment: @RoshanGautam i want all the tabs with same small width.

Comment: Can you send a design or sketch of how you want your TabBar to look like ? @waheed-akhtar

Comment: @RoshanGautam is stackoverflow don't allow me to put image because my reputation is less.